# NumPy: convert decimals to fractions

Tags: python, numpy, decimal, fractions

I compute the reverse of matrix **A**, for instance,

```
import numpy as np

A = np.diag([1, 2, 3])
A_inv = np.linalg.pinv(A)
print(A_inv)
```

I got,

```
[[ 1.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.5         0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.33333333]]
```

But, I want this,

```
[[ 1.          0.          0. ]
 [ 0.          1/2         0. ]
 [ 0.          0.          1/3]]
```

I tried `np.set_printoptions`,

```
import fractions
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'all':lambda x: str(fractions.Fraction(x))})
print(A_inv)
```

but I got this,

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1/2 0]
 [0 0 6004799503160661/18014398509481984]]
```

How do I convert decimals to fractions in NumPy?

Comment: Are you just talking about the representation when printing it?  Or do you actually want `numpy` to invert the matrix using something like `fractions.Fraction`?

Comment: @mgilson, just for print purpose.

Comment: you are running into floating point issues, try something like `lambda x: str(fractions.Fraction(x).limit_denominator())`

Comment: @jeremycg, it works:-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a floating point issue - recall that 2/3 is not exactly 2/3 in Pythons representation.

The Fraction class has a built in method, `limit_denominator()`, to take care of this:

```
import fractions
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'all':lambda x: str(fractions.Fraction(x).limit_denominator())})
print(A_inv)
```

Which gives the desired answer:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1/2 0]
 [0 0 1/3]]
```

Comment: Be aware that `limit_denominator` is doing something very specific, namely finding the closest rational approximation with denominator not exceeding 1 million. That may or may not be appropriate, depending on the use-case. In particular, it's not going to give particularly good results for very large or very small numbers.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you have any idea to format print each elements into fixed width? I used `np.set_printoptions(formatter={'str_kind': '{10s}'.format}`, but didn't work.

Comment: how to use a comma as separator instead of spaces